# How to import QuartCore in iOS5/XCode 4.3?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, quartz-core

In iOS4 I used the following import statement

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Now in iOS5 in XCode 4.3 even though the QuartzCore.framework is included when I type in

```
#import <
```

only QuartzCore is displayed in the intellisense whereas QuartzCord/QuartzCore.h was displayed previously. If I type in the full definition everything works fine.

Is this a bug or has the import definition changed in iOS5/XCode 4.3?

EDIT: Just installed XCode 4.3.1 and have the same problem w/ several frameworks.

Comment: I've been having problems like this since day 1. I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea thats a problem in new xcode.Type `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If I include the `QuartzCore.framework` in the project settings (Top entry in the left sidebar = Project Navigator -> Targets -> BuildPhases -> Link Binary with Library) I can type 
`#import <Q` and `QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` is provided by IntelliSense.

Comment: What version of XCode are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 4.3.1 (4E1019)